# Arabic (Farsi) font won't let my half-space work, But in inspect it works fine by copy and pasting the same code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fonts, arabic

Running the snippet, you can see a comment section for products.
I wrote some JavaScript code to get the first and last name of users and put their first letter in a little box which is blue.

The problem is the language uses Arabic(Farsi) Fonts and when the user name is for example علی حسینی (in Arabic font) it displays عح in the blue box.
But i want it to display like ع ح with no space (separated like semi-space between the two letter's but even thinner than semi-space). I wanna reach something like you see at the picture:
[image]
So I decided to use `&hairsp;` instead of using space(semi-space) between two letter's.

But it doesn't work when JS add this code and in inspect when I copy and paste the same code it works fine.
I thought the problem is with the letter fonts so I changed my code to `&#8082;` or `;8082#&` and others. But the problem is still here with no result, despite the fact there is no error or warnings and JS is working fine otherwise.

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.commentAttr = function(options) {

    $(".upndata-m7").each(function() {

      var full_name = $(this).find(".untx-m7").text();


      var name_split = full_name.split(" ");
      var first_name_letter = '';
      var last_name_letter = '';



      if (typeof(name_split[0]) != "undefined" && name_split[0] !== null && name_split !== '') {
        var first_name = name_split[0];
        first_name_letter = first_name.charAt(0);
      }

      if (typeof(name_split[1]) != "undefined" && name_split[1] !== null && name_split !== '') {
        var last_name = name_split[1];
        last_name_letter = last_name.charAt(0);
      }


      $(this).find('.usrpic-tpl-s1 figure').attr("data-img", first_name_letter + '&hairsp;' + last_name_letter);


    });
  };
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function() {

  $.fn.commentAttr();

});
```

```css
.usrpic-tpl-s1 figure[data-img] {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.usrpic-tpl-s1 figure[data-img].c1-s1 {
  background-color: rgba(62, 158, 232, .8)
}

.usrpic-tpl-s1 figure[data-img].c2-s1 {
  background-color: rgba(232, 150, 62, .8)
}

.usrpic-tpl-s1 figure[data-img].c3-s1 {
  background-color: rgba(241, 3, 70, .8)
}

.usrpic-tpl-s1 figure[data-img]::after {
  content: attr(data-img);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: rem(21);
  font-weight: 800;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .uaitms-m7 {
  padding-top: 35px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .uaitms-m7 .ucctn-m7 {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 45px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .uaitms-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 {
  position: relative
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .uaitms-m7 .ucmain-m7 {
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.good-m7 .uctxt-m7 {
  background-color: rgba(73, 187, 94, .06)
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.good-m7 .uctxstar-m7 .ucrcmnd-m7 {
  background-color: #49bb5e
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.bad-m7 .uctxt-m7 {
  background-color: rgba(235, 45, 90, .06)
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.bad-m7 .uctxstar-m7 .ucrcmnd-m7 {
  background-color: #eb2d5a
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucmain-m7 {
  margin-bottom: 40px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxt-m7 {
  background-color: rgba(231, 123, 51, .06);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 20px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxt-m7 .tx-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: rem(15);
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucinftx-m7 {
  margin-bottom: 15px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 {
  margin-bottom: 35px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 .upndata-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 140px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 .upndata-m7 .usrpic-tpl-s1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 10px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 .upndata-m7 .uname-m7 {
  display: inline-block
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .userprp-tpl-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .lctn-m7 .ucinftx-m7 .usrpic-tpl-s1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .lctn-m7 .ucinftx-m7 .uname-m7 {
  display: inline-block
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .upndata-m7 .uname-m7 {
  margin-bottom: 6px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .upndata-m7 .untx-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: rem(18);
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 30px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .upndata-m7 .udtx-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: rem(15);
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #78797b
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 {
  text-align: left
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .ubitms-m7 ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 38px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .ubitms-m7 ul li:last-child {
  margin-left: 0
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .btxicn-m7 {
  padding: 0
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .btxicn-m7.like-m7:hover .nf {
  background-color: rgba(235, 45, 90, .1);
  color: rgba(235, 45, 90, .7)
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .btxicn-m7:hover .nf {
  background-color: rgba(57, 145, 233, .1);
  color: rgba(57, 145, 233, .75)
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .btxicn-m7:hover .ubtx-m7 {
  color: rgba(40, 40, 40, .8)
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .btxicn-m7 .nf {
  font-size: px(15);
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(91, 91, 91, .05);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: rgba(91, 91, 91, .2);
  transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  margin-left: 8px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .btxicn-m7 .ubtx-m7 {
  font-size: rem(15);
  color: rgba(91, 91, 91, .8)
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxstar-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 21px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxstar-m7 .stars-tpl-m7 {
  text-align: left;
  float: left
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxstar-m7 .ucrcmnd-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 107px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e77b33;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px 0 2px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxstar-m7 .ucrcmnd-m7 .ubtx-m7 {
  font-size: rem(12)
}

@media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 .upndata-m7 {
    width: auto;
    max-width: inherit
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .in-answer-m7 {
    padding: 30px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .txtcmmnt-tpl-m7 {
    padding-right: 150px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 {
    padding-top: 40px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.good-m7 .ucinftx-m7 {
    background-color: rgba(73, 187, 94, .06)
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.good-m7 .uctxt-m7 {
    background-color: transparent
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.bad-m7 .ucinftx-m7 {
    background-color: rgba(235, 45, 90, .06)
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.bad-m7 .uctxt-m7 {
    background-color: transparent
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucmain-m7 {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 120px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 .upndata-m7 {
    display: none
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .lctn-m7 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .lctn-m7 .upndata-m7 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 11px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxstar-m7 {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxstar-m7 .stars-tpl-m7 {
    float: unset;
    margin-bottom: 13px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucinftx-m7 {
    background-color: rgba(231, 123, 51, .06);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-radius: 50px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxt-m7 {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-top: 30px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxt-m7 .tx-m7 {
    line-height: 36px
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:992px) {
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .uaitms-m7>ul>li {
    padding: 0 35px
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1200px) {
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .uaitms-m7>ul>li {
    padding: 0 135px
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="usercmmnt-tpl-m7 ucanswr-m7">
  <div class="ucctn-m7">
    <div class="ucmain-m7">

      <div class="lctn-m7">
        <div class="ucinftx-m7">
          <div class="upndata-m7">
            <div class="usrpic-tpl-s1">
              <figure class="c1-s1" data-img="رم"></figure>
            </div>
            <div class="uname-m7">
              <span class="untx-m7">علی حسینی</span>
            </div>
            <div class="udata-m7">
              <span class="udtx-m7">17 شهریور 98</span>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: I didn't change the lines where you said "*it displays عح in the blue box.
But i want it to display like ع ح with no space.*" but shouldn't it be *it displays ع ح in the blue box.
But i want it to display like عح with no space.*?

Comment: @Kaiido ==> with no space (separated like semi-space but even thinner than semi-space) added, Sorry if i confused you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity you want is the [Zero Width Non-Joiner Character (U+200C)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm)

```js
const letters = [ "\u0639", "\u062D" ];
console.log( letters.join( "" ) );
console.log( letters.join( "\u200c" ) );
```

Its HTML entity is `&#8204;` but since you are setting an attribute and not an innerHTML, you need a javascript escaped form instead (`"\u200C"`):

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.commentAttr = function(options) {

    $(".upndata-m7").each(function() {

      var full_name = $(this).find(".untx-m7").text();


      var name_split = full_name.split(" ");
      var first_name_letter = '';
      var last_name_letter = '';



      if (typeof(name_split[0]) != "undefined" && name_split[0] !== null && name_split !== '') {
        var first_name = name_split[0];
        first_name_letter = first_name.charAt(0);
      }

      if (typeof(name_split[1]) != "undefined" && name_split[1] !== null && name_split !== '') {
        var last_name = name_split[1];
        last_name_letter = last_name.charAt(0);
      }


      $(this).find('.usrpic-tpl-s1 figure').attr("data-img", first_name_letter + '\u200c' + last_name_letter);


    });
  };
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function() {

  $.fn.commentAttr();

});
```

```css
.usrpic-tpl-s1 figure[data-img] {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.usrpic-tpl-s1 figure[data-img].c1-s1 {
  background-color: rgba(62, 158, 232, .8)
}

.usrpic-tpl-s1 figure[data-img].c2-s1 {
  background-color: rgba(232, 150, 62, .8)
}

.usrpic-tpl-s1 figure[data-img].c3-s1 {
  background-color: rgba(241, 3, 70, .8)
}

.usrpic-tpl-s1 figure[data-img]::after {
  content: attr(data-img);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: rem(21);
  font-weight: 800;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .uaitms-m7 {
  padding-top: 35px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .uaitms-m7 .ucctn-m7 {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 45px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .uaitms-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 {
  position: relative
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .uaitms-m7 .ucmain-m7 {
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.good-m7 .uctxt-m7 {
  background-color: rgba(73, 187, 94, .06)
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.good-m7 .uctxstar-m7 .ucrcmnd-m7 {
  background-color: #49bb5e
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.bad-m7 .uctxt-m7 {
  background-color: rgba(235, 45, 90, .06)
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.bad-m7 .uctxstar-m7 .ucrcmnd-m7 {
  background-color: #eb2d5a
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucmain-m7 {
  margin-bottom: 40px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxt-m7 {
  background-color: rgba(231, 123, 51, .06);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 20px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxt-m7 .tx-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: rem(15);
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucinftx-m7 {
  margin-bottom: 15px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 {
  margin-bottom: 35px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 .upndata-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 140px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 .upndata-m7 .usrpic-tpl-s1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 10px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 .upndata-m7 .uname-m7 {
  display: inline-block
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .userprp-tpl-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .lctn-m7 .ucinftx-m7 .usrpic-tpl-s1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .lctn-m7 .ucinftx-m7 .uname-m7 {
  display: inline-block
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .upndata-m7 .uname-m7 {
  margin-bottom: 6px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .upndata-m7 .untx-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: rem(18);
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 30px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .upndata-m7 .udtx-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: rem(15);
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #78797b
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 {
  text-align: left
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .ubitms-m7 ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 38px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .ubitms-m7 ul li:last-child {
  margin-left: 0
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .btxicn-m7 {
  padding: 0
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .btxicn-m7.like-m7:hover .nf {
  background-color: rgba(235, 45, 90, .1);
  color: rgba(235, 45, 90, .7)
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .btxicn-m7:hover .nf {
  background-color: rgba(57, 145, 233, .1);
  color: rgba(57, 145, 233, .75)
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .btxicn-m7:hover .ubtx-m7 {
  color: rgba(40, 40, 40, .8)
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .btxicn-m7 .nf {
  font-size: px(15);
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(91, 91, 91, .05);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: rgba(91, 91, 91, .2);
  transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  margin-left: 8px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucbtm-m7 .btxicn-m7 .ubtx-m7 {
  font-size: rem(15);
  color: rgba(91, 91, 91, .8)
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxstar-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 21px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxstar-m7 .stars-tpl-m7 {
  text-align: left;
  float: left
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxstar-m7 .ucrcmnd-m7 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 107px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e77b33;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px 0 2px
}

.usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxstar-m7 .ucrcmnd-m7 .ubtx-m7 {
  font-size: rem(12)
}

@media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 .upndata-m7 {
    width: auto;
    max-width: inherit
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .in-answer-m7 {
    padding: 30px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .txtcmmnt-tpl-m7 {
    padding-right: 150px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 {
    padding-top: 40px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.good-m7 .ucinftx-m7 {
    background-color: rgba(73, 187, 94, .06)
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.good-m7 .uctxt-m7 {
    background-color: transparent
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.bad-m7 .ucinftx-m7 {
    background-color: rgba(235, 45, 90, .06)
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7.bad-m7 .uctxt-m7 {
    background-color: transparent
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucmain-m7 {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 120px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .rctn-m7 .upndata-m7 {
    display: none
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .lctn-m7 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .lctn-m7 .upndata-m7 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 11px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxstar-m7 {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxstar-m7 .stars-tpl-m7 {
    float: unset;
    margin-bottom: 13px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .ucinftx-m7 {
    background-color: rgba(231, 123, 51, .06);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-radius: 50px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxt-m7 {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-top: 30px
  }
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7 .ucctn-m7 .uctxt-m7 .tx-m7 {
    line-height: 36px
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:992px) {
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .uaitms-m7>ul>li {
    padding: 0 35px
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1200px) {
  .usercmmnt-tpl-m7.ucanswr-m7 .uaitms-m7>ul>li {
    padding: 0 135px
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="usercmmnt-tpl-m7 ucanswr-m7">
  <div class="ucctn-m7">
    <div class="ucmain-m7">

      <div class="lctn-m7">
        <div class="ucinftx-m7">
          <div class="upndata-m7">
            <div class="usrpic-tpl-s1">
              <figure class="c1-s1" data-img="رم"></figure>
            </div>
            <div class="uname-m7">
              <span class="untx-m7">علی حسینی</span>
            </div>
            <div class="udata-m7">
              <span class="udtx-m7">17 شهریور 98</span>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```